# Render partial or action inside thickbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I call the action, the action should open up the thick box with the value.

So for that I have used something like thing, but it didn't work

```
def call
  render :action=>"call_page", :class=>"thickbox"
end
```

and also used

```
def call
  render :partial=>"call_page", :class=>"thickbox"
end
```

so, please tell me how I can go with this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [facebox_render](http://github.com/franciscoj/facebox_render) plugin's code can give you an example of how to do it.